# How to render css as style inside shadow dom in react typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass, shadow-dom

I have been trying to render my css codes as internal css inside react component in shadow dom boundry.
I have one css file and scss file. I like to render my css inside the app.tsx file as inline css.

```
 <style>
          // css code here
        </style>
```

From past two days I have tryed different different solution but it doesn't work. I have tryed styled-component package using createGlobalStyle but it's not working. Please help me this is the github repo https://github.com/rejoan121615/Digital_Assistant_Client.git

I am trying to render my css code as internal css.